# Replacing missing values with the mean

Tags: r, data-cleaning

Please help me understand the below syntax :

I am trying to fit the NA with the mean of the data available but could not understand the following syntax, someone please help me to understand the below syntax.

```
data$Age[is.na(data$Age)] <- mean(data$Age,na.rm=T)
```

Comment: This should be discussed in most intro to R tutorials regarding replacing values within a data.frame. It says: replace missing values of variable Age with the mean value of Age in data.frame (poorly) named data. See the well written help files `?"["` and `?is.na` as well as `?mean`.

Comment: The right-hand side of the assignment `<-`, for the left-hand side the concepts that you need to understand are named `data.frame` and `subsetting`.

Answer (score -1):

`data$Age[is.na(data$Age)] <- mean(data$Age,na.rm=T)`

#### Explanation

**The right-hand side `RHS`**

`data$Age` - refers to the column `Age` in data.frame `data`
`mean(data$Age,na.rm=T)` - calculate mean of column ignoring values equal to `NA`

**The left-hand side `LHS`**

`is.na(data$Age)` - return TRUE/FALSE vector where `data$Age` is equal to `NA`; this corresponds to rows that contain a `NA` in the `Age` column
`<-` - assign to LHS the value calculated on RHS
`data$Age[is.na(data$Age)] <-` - For `data$Age` where above is true, assign value on RHS